# First running of MySQL/workbench but throws error of 'wrong password'?

Tags: mysql, passwords, workbench

I just installed workbench with MySQL and tried to make local connection.
but it throws error of 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (1045)'.
I googled this and it seems to be error of wrong password.
I wasn't asked to set any password during my installation.
is there any default password mysql workbench?

this is what I've downloaded: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/
and this is the capture of error message.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I thought mysql is included in the installer but it wasn't.
Installed mysql itself first and used the installer and now it works.